# Find sphere intersection point

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, graphing-functions, spheres

I have a sphere which is originated at:

$$
    \begin{matrix}
    0 & 0 & 0
    \end{matrix}
$$

Its radius **r** is 150. I have a line which goes from: $$
    \begin{matrix}
    0 & 0 & 0
    \end{matrix}
$$

and passes through the point inside a sphere [x y z]. Knowing that line starts from origin and crosses [x y z], how to find out at what coordinates line will intersect with the sphere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line consists of the points $[\lambda x,\lambda y,\lambda z]$ with $\lambda\in\Bbb{R}$. The sphere consists of the points $[u,v,w]$ with
$$u^2+v^2+w^2=150^2.$$
So the points of intersection are the points $[\lambda x,\lambda y,\lambda z]$ with $\lambda\in\Bbb{R}$ such that
$$(\lambda x)^2+(\lambda y)^2+(\lambda z)^2=150^2.$$
It is not hard to see that the appropriate values for $\lambda$ are
$$\lambda=\pm\sqrt{\frac{150^2}{x^2+y^2+z^2}}=\pm\frac{150}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}}.$$

Comment: Thanks for perfect answer!